# Calculated case statment in a switch (java)

Tags: java, optimization, switch-statement

I've been asking myself this question for a while, it's a basic one, but I've never been able to do it any other way

The **goal** is to eliminate `else if` in code

I actually have this:

```
String contentType = parser.getMimeMessage().getContentType().toLowerCase(); 
//contentType can be for example: "text/a; charset=us-ascii"

String content = parser.getPlainContent(); 

if (contentType.indexOf("text/a") > 0) {
 processTextA(content);

} else if (contentType.indexOf("text/b") > 0) {
 processTextB(content);

} else if (contentType.indexOf("text/c") > 0) {
 processTextC(content);
}
```

What I'd like to do is something similar to this:

```
String contentType = parser.getMimeMessage().getContentType().toLowerCase();
//contentType can be for example: "text/a; charset=us-ascii"

String content = parser.getPlainContent();

switch (contentType) {
 case (contentType.indexOf("text/a") > 0):
  processTextA(content);
  break;

 case (contentType.indexOf("text/b") > 0):
  processTextB(content);
  break;

 case (contentType.indexOf("text/c") > 0):
  processTextC(content);
  break;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve something similar to this?

In the example I put 3 `else if` but the reality is that **I have about 20  `else if` one behind the other**

**EDIT**

contentType can be `text/a; charset=us-ascii`, however, it can also be `charset=us-ascii; text/a;`

I can't trust the sender to meet any specifications because it's a private communication protocol between companies so `split` can't be used

I gave that as an example, but the question is that the **case statment needs to be calculated**

Comment: Just to clarify: Are the else-ifs actually nested? That would mean there are else-ifs inside of else-ifs.

Comment: No, I didn't explain correctly, I meant there's one behind the other @Dejke

Comment: Sorry, but case statements can only be constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The *goal* is to eliminate `else if` in code

There's nothing wrong with else-if as long as you keep it simple. But here you are:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor // https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor.html
enum MyContentType {
    NONE(""),
    A("text/a"),
    B("text/a"),
    C("text/a"),
    ;

    static MyContentType from(String contentTypeHeader) {
        final String header = contentTypeHeader.toLowerCase();
        return Arrays.stream(MyContentType.values())
                .skip(1)
                .filter(e -> header.contains(e.headerSubstring))
                .findFirst().orElse(NONE);
    }

    private final String headerSubstring;
}
```

and then switch on the `MyContentType` member.

---

> In the example I put 3 else if but the reality is that *I have about 20 `else if` one behind the other*

What's the concern?

- If readability, then make sure, you don't do anything but a single simple method call inside. Or use my approach.
- If speed, then be assured that the processing usually takes many orders of magnitude more time. As the string are known in advance, you could optimize using some smart algorithm, but that's most probably waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I'd use:

```
contentType.contains("text/a")
```

instead of:

```
contentType.indexOf("text/a") > 0
```

If I understood you correctly, there can be only one `contentType` in your `MimeMessage` (deduced that by the fact that you used `else if` instead of `if`). You can simply split the `contentType` by `;` to get desired part of the string. Then, you can switch case on the string. Something like this:

```
String contentType = parser.getMimeMessage().getContentType().toLowerCase();
//contentType can be for example: "text/a; charset=us-ascii"

String content = parser.getPlainContent();

String contentTypeSplitted = contentType.split(";")[0];
switch (contentTypeSplitted) {
 case ("text/a"):
  processTextA(content);
  break;

 case ("text/b"):
  processTextB(content);
  break;

 case ("text/c"):
  processTextC(content);
  break;
}
```

Comment: Exactly, there will only be one contentType, However, it won't always be in position 0 @null

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create a map of textType -> operation. 
For example:

```
 static Map<String, Consumer<String>> operationMap = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        operationMap.put("text/a", this::processTextA);
        operationMap.put("text/b", this::processTextC);
    }

    public static void process(String contentType, String content) {
      operationMap.get(content).accept(content)
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how that can work if contentType is a value like "text/a; charset=us-ascii"

Comment: It's about replacing 20+ if statements. To parse content type, you can use `contentType.contains(";") ? contentType.split(";")[0] : contentType`

Comment: But it won't always be in position 0

Comment: Why?  According to specification Content-Type is `Content-Type:= type [";" ver-num [";" 1#resource-ref]] [comment]` https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1049, it can contain `;` - then jsut get everything before `;`, or it can be without `;`, then in most cases the whole word should be type

Comment: I like your answer, but, unfortunately, I cannot trust that the specifications will be followed.
It is a program that is used as a means of communication established between multiple companies to exchange messages and seeing how some things are done I see it as unlikely to always be in the first position.
The contentType also does not follow the standard